# Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, nsxmlparser

Im parsing an XML with NSXMLParser like say in Apple Developer Documentation.

Im do the parser fine, but when i want put in an NSString the Object parser there is an error, with SIGABRT.

The exception is:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClinicasAsociadasProfesionales objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x606c8c0'
```

Im save the objects in te NSMutableArray like:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
                         didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                         namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                         qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Clinicas"])
    {
        return;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Clinica"]) 
    {
        [arrayClinicas addObject: varClinicasAsociadasProfesionales];
        [varClinicasAsociadasProfesionales release];
    }


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NombreClinica"])
    {
        [varClinicasAsociadasProfesionales setValue:soapResults forKey:elementName];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"IdClinica"])
    {
        [varClinicasAsociadasProfesionales setValue:soapResults forKey:elementName];
    }

    soapResults=nil;
    [soapResults release];
    elementoEncontrado = NO; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

crash is not for this code ..somewhere you are using

```
[ClinicasAsociadasProfesionales objectForKey:]
```

Instead you should use

```
[ClinicasAsociadasProfesionales valueForKey:]
```

as you are using setValue:ForKey: methos to set a value to ClinicasAsociadasProfesionales object